# Create Network with Email and Account Duplicates

Tags: r, networking

I'm trying to create a network which maps connections between accounts and emails where there are many-to-many relationships. The data looks something like

### Account    |  Email

1. 123  |    jane_doe@123.com
2. 152  |     john_doe@123.com
3. 123  |     john_doe@123.com

---

So obviously there are duplicates, and igraph does not like this. Along with this, my version of R will not allow me to use the SNA package, since I cannot download the statnet.common package.

I have tried looking at different tutorials for this, but all I've been able to see is cases where you have one column and want to create edges within that column, not between two columns with duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

To remove duplicates try using the `unique()` function on the array

For example, if we have an array `x <- c("a","a","a","c","d")`

running `unique(x)` outputs: "a" "c" "d"

If you'd like more help though, present the actual dataframe using dput() and upload it on the forum. Check this out: [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)